# QFileDialog crashes/hangs in Windows 11

Tags: qt, windows-11, qfiledialog

I am trying to read a folder name, but when opening QFileDialog it hangs or crashes and app stops. I have tried several options and configurations.

I have tried different options such as DontuseNativeDialog and others.
The funny thing is that this code was working in a dev environment under Windows 10.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QString folderName = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),"C:\\",QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Unlikely due to Windows or Qt but more likely has to do with the rest of code in your application. Not enough to scope.

Comment: Create minimum reproducible example and then show its code. This way we can exclude effects of the code that you did not show.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. Actually I already created a project exclusively with the published code, to exclude any influence as well as to reduce compilation time. 
Then, project has only Mainwindow class which is exec from main.
Understand that it is probable not W11 nor Qt, but this single code is not able to run. It crashes when dialog opens to select folder name. No chance to click on anything before.

Any hint is well received.